# An example of projective curves and how to find its dimension

Tags: abstract-algebra, algebraic-geometry, polynomials, commutative-algebra, projective-geometry

Let $\mathbb{C}$ be the complex field and $\mathbb{C} [x, y, z]$ be a three-variable polynomial ring.

$A = \mathbb{C} [x, y, z] / (y ^ 2z-x ^ 3 + 2z ^ 3)$ is an integral domain.

Let the image of $f \in \mathbb{C} [x, y, z]$ in $A$ be $\overline{f}$.
Let $ Q (A) $ be the field of fractions of $ A $.

$K = \{\overline{f} / \overline{g} \mid \text{$f, g$ are homogeneous polynomials and $\deg (f) = \deg (g)$}\}\cup\{0\}$

is a subfield of $Q (A)$.

I think $K$ is a function field of an elliptic curve defined by $y ^ 2 = x ^ 3-2$. Therefore, the transcendence degree of $K$ over $\mathbb{C}$ should be $1$.

Please show that the transcendence degree over $\mathbb{C}$ of $K$ is $1$.

Comment: Hint: If $C:=Proj(k[x,y,z]/(f))$, on the open set $D(z) \subseteq C$ it follows $D(z)\cong Spec(k[u,v]/(u^2-v^3+2)$, and $dim(D(z))=1= trdeg_k(K(C))$ where $K(C)$ is the quotient field of $C$. You must prove that $K \cong K(C)$.

Comment: The quotient field $K(C)$ is isomorphic to the quotientfield $Q(B)$ where $B:=k[u,v]/(u^2-v^3+2)$. Here $u:=y/z, v:=x/z$.

Comment: There apperars to be a well defined map $\phi:k[u,v] \rightarrow Q(A)$ defined by $\phi(u):=y/z, \phi(v):=x/z$ satisfying $\phi(u^2-v^3+2)=\frac{1}{z^3}f=0$. Hence you get a map $\phi^*: k[u,v]/(u^2-v^3+2) \rightarrow Q(A)$ and  a map $\tilde{\phi}: Q(B) \rightarrow Q(A)$.

Comment: Note: Here you must prove that  $ker(\phi)=(u^2-v^3+2)$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Question:** "Please show that the transcendence degree on $C$ of $K$ is 1."

**Answer:** The map $\phi$ has the following property: let $f(u,v)\in k[u,v]$ with $f(u,v):=\sum_{i+j \leq d}\alpha_{(i,j)}v^iu^j$. It follows

$$\phi(f):= \sum_{i,j} \alpha_{(i,j)}(x/z)^i(y/z)^j =$$

$$ \frac{1}{z^d}\sum_{i,j} \alpha_{(i,j)}x^iy^j z^{d-(i+j)}= \frac{F(x,y,z)}{z^d}$$

where $F$ is a homogeneous polynomial of degree $d$. Hence $\phi(f) \in K$ is in your subring $K \subseteq Q(A)$. Since $Q(B)$ is a field and $\phi$ is a map of rings, you get an injective map of rings

$$\phi: Q(B) \rightarrow K$$

and it remains to prove that this map is surjective. An element in $K$ is on the form $\frac{F(x,y,z)}{G(x,y,z)}$ where $F,G$ are homogeneous polynomials of the same degree $d$ and you may write $F=z^df(x/z,y/z)$ where $f(u,v)$ is a polynomial of degree $\leq d$ and similar for $G=z^dg(x/z,y/z)$. Hence

$$\frac{F}{G}=\frac{z^df(x/z,y/z)}{z^dg(x/z,y/z)} \cong \frac{f(x/z,y/z)}{g(x/z,y/z)}.$$

It follows

$$\phi(\frac{f(v,u)}{g(v,u)})=\frac{F}{G}$$

and the map $\phi$ is surjective.

Comment: Thank you for your detailed explanation.
By showing $ Q (A) = Q (B) $, it becomes the case of affine.

Comment: @Kazsugi - you should verify that $ker(\phi)=(u^2-v^3+2)$.